# how to have a dimmed version of google maps indicating that it's night time

Tags: google-maps

Many times when using google maps gps at time time i notice a dimmed version of the map and also when you going inside a tunnel. How do I create a dimmed version of google maps that indicates that is night time?

Answer (score 1):

You can style your maps using this [wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

Check out [this blog](http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2014/01/12/luminosity/) on creating custom media queries that react to light levels

for example:

```
@media screen and (luminosity: normal) {
  body {background-color: #ddd; color: #111;}
}
@media screen and (luminosity: dim) {
  body {background-color: #444; color: #fff;}
}
```

Combine the two and you'll be able to create a similar effect with your maps, i.e. they change style depending on light levels. The tricky thing is the wizard generates the style with JS so you may need to also add and remove classes to add the styling. Hope this helps

Comment: I know it's not a complete solution but hopefully putting the two together will get you a bit closer to your goal :)